# Is there a good way to not expose certain struct attributes in json payloads?

Tags: go

I was really hoping the below code would work, but it doesn't so currently I have to manually set values from one struct to another.

https://play.golang.org/p/yfcsaNJm9M

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type A struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

type B struct {
    A
    Password string `json:"-"`
    Locale   string `json:"locale"`
}

func main() {

    a := A{"Jim", "some_secret_password"}
    b := B{A: a, Locale: "en"}

    data, _ := json.Marshal(&b)
    fmt.Printf("%v", string(data))
}
```

Output...I don't want to show the secret field

```
{"name":"Jim","password":"some_secret_password","locale":"en"}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/HdwIssr-oC Is that you expecting?

Comment: That is what I'm looking for :) I would never have expected that to work though.

Comment: @PravinMishra you should post is as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field
>   becomes a member of the object unless

```
- the field's tag is "-", or
- the field is empty and its tag specifies the "omitempty" option.
```

> The empty values are false, 0, any nil pointer or interface value, and
>   any array, slice, map, or string of length zero. The object's default
>   key string is the struct field name but can be specified in the struct
>   field's tag value. The "json" key in the struct field's tag value is
>   the key name, followed by an optional comma and options. Examples:

```
// Field is ignored by this package.
Field int `json:"-"`

// Field appears in JSON as key "myName".
Field int `json:"myName"`

// Field appears in JSON as key "myName" and
// the field is omitted from the object if its value is     empty,
// as defined above.
Field int `json:"myName,omitempty"`

// Field appears in JSON as key "Field" (the default), but
// the field is skipped if empty.
// Note the leading comma.
Field int `json:",omitempty"`
```

So your code should be:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type A struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

type B struct {
    A
    Password string `json:"password,omitempty"`
    Locale   string `json:"locale"`
}

func main() {

    a := A{"Jim", "some_secret_password"}
    b := B{A: a, Locale: "en"}

    data, _ := json.Marshal(&b)
    fmt.Printf("%v", string(data))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HdwIssr-oC